# Legendre Polynomial manipulations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, numerical-methods, summation, legendre-polynomials

Given Legendre polynomial generating function
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n (x) t^n  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-2xt+t^2)}}
\end{equation}
Show that $$  P_n (1)=1 $$ and $$ P_n (-1)=(-1)^n $$

Not sure where to start with either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $ x=1 $ in the given equation yields

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n (1) t^n  = \frac{1}{(1-2t+t^2)^{\frac12}} = \frac{1}{((1-t)^2)^{\frac12}} = = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n  $$

which gives $P_n(1)=1$. You can do the same with the other one.

Answer (score 1):

substitute $x=1$:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n (1) t^n  = \frac{1}{(1-2t+t^2)^{\frac12}}
= \frac{1}{((1-t)^2)^{\frac12}} = \frac{1}{1-t}
$$
and can you expand that in powers of $t$?

Similar method for $x=-1$.